# Get the sub colnames of a dataframe from SPSS to R (read.spss)

Tags: r, import, spss

i'm new to stack overflow, i have a question.

When i import a dataframe from spss to R with the function `read.spss` it appears in the colnames two elements: the name of the column and a "sub name" of the column like in the image below:

[image: image in Rstudio]

This "sub-colnames" refers to the column Label in SPSS (variable View) like in the image below:
[image]

My question is: Is there a function that can tell me in the console all the sub-colnames like with the function `colnames(dataframe)` ? Also, this function could tell me the colname and the subcolname of each column at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`help(read.spss)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/foreign/html/read.spss.html) the attribute variable.labels has the columns labels

```r
df <- read.spss("file")
attr(df, "variable.labels")
```

Comment: Thanks very much, very useful.

Comment: @SantiagoSotelo if the answer solves the question please accept it so future users have easier access to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Abdessabour Mtk for your answer, i used it to came with this efficient solution:

`labels <- attr(enaho17.2, "variable.labels")                                                    labels <- data.frame(labels)                                                                     number <- which(rownames(labels) == "**P203**")                                               rownames(labels)[number]; labels[number, ]                                               rownames(labels)`

Comment: Do somebody know how can i turn this into a function?